# Change the Menu background when clicked in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, menuitem

I'm using the below code to style a `Menu`. I have been able to change the background when the `Mouse` is `Over` the menu. But I don't know how to change its `Background` when it is clicked.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalColor">White</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverColor">LightGray</SolidColorBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ClickedColor">DarkGray</SolidColorBrush>

        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Menu">
                        <Border x:Name="MainMenu" Background="{StaticResource NormalColor}"
                                BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1">
                            <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MainMenu" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoverColor}"/>
                            </Trigger>                           
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>                        
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Menu Width="30" Height="20" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**
I have tried the following code but it didn't work either.

```
<Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="MainMenu" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ClickedColor}"/>
</Trigger
```

Comment: What do you mean, is clicked? The Click is an event, not a state. You may be thinking about IsFocused. This requires the MenuItem to be focused.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen I honestly searched a lot in the Google. I have not been able to find a decent tutorial to do this. Can you point me in the right direction. Thank you very much.

Comment: For Focus, the MSDN documentation is a good read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @TroelsLarsen Thanks. I tried the updated code above but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please try to elaborate on what you mean by 'clicked' without using technical terms. Do you mean that once you press you LMB on the element, it should change colour - if so, how long?

Comment: @TroelsLarsen you know like when you click the `File` menu, its background changes as far as the mouse is over the enabled menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using IsKeyboardFocusWithin.

```
<Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="MainMenu" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ClickedColor}"/>
</Trigger>
```

Here is your code with the IsKeyboardFocusWithin trigger added. I changed the ClickedColor to Purple so it is easier to see. I added Name="mm" to your menu. I added a stack panel with textblocks bound to mm.IsFocused and mm.IsKeyboardFocusWithin so you can visually see what they are set to and when it changes.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalColor">White</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverColor">LightGray</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ClickedColor">Purple</SolidColorBrush>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Menu">
                    <Border x:Name="MainMenu" Background="{StaticResource NormalColor}"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainMenu" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoverColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainMenu" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ClickedColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu Width="30" Height="20" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Name="mm">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="menu.IsFocused:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mm, Path=IsFocused}" />
        <TextBlock Text="menu.IsKeyboardFocusWithin:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mm, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

OK, for the menu item... try this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication11.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalColor">White</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="HoverColor">LightGray</SolidColorBrush>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ClickedColor">Purple</SolidColorBrush>

    <Style x:Key="{x:Type Menu}" TargetType="Menu">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Menu">
                    <Border x:Name="MainMenu" Background="{StaticResource NormalColor}"
                            BorderBrush="Black"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="MainMenu" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HoverColor}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MenuItemControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="F1M10,1.2L4.7,9.1 4.5,9.1 0,5.2 1.3,3.5 4.3,6.1 8.3,0 10,1.2z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FF999999" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFF0F0F0" Padding="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Fill="#FFD7D7D7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#3D26A0DA"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF26A0DA"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="#FF707070"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FF707070"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="templateRoot" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ClickedColor}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Menu Width="100" Height="20" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File" Name="mm" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
            <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="_Edit" Template="{DynamicResource MenuItemControlTemplate1}">
            <MenuItem Header="_Copy"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Cut"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Paste"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="menuitem.IsFocused:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mm, Path=IsFocused}" />
        <TextBlock Text="menuitem.IsKeyboardFocusWithin:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=mm, Path=IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this changes the `Background` of the entire menu. So if I have several Header Menus the background for all of them changes. I want to change them individually.

Comment: You're welcome. I accidentally left "<Setter Property="Header" Value="Test" />" in the trigger (it doesn't do anything/work). I've updated the answer so it isn't there. If you've copied it already, update your copy.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. I was lost for a day or so.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an event handler to the `Menu.PreviewMouseDown` event and change the `Background` there. Try this:

```
<Menu Width="30" Height="20" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Background="White" PreviewMouseDown="Menu_PreviewMouseDown">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

...

```
private void Menu_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Menu menu = (Menu)sender;
    menu.Background = Brushes.DarkGray;
}
```

If you just want it to change colour while the mouse button is held down, then you could attach a handler to the `MenuItem.PreviewMouseUp` event to change it back to `White`.

---

UPDATE >>>

You can add a handler to the `MouseLeave` event to change the Background`back when the mouse cursor leaves the bounds of the`Menu`. Try this:

```
<Menu Width="30" Height="20" Margin="10, 10, 5, 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Background="White" PreviewMouseDown="Menu_PreviewMouseDown" 
    MouseLeave="Menu_MouseLeave">
    <MenuItem Header="_File">
        <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Open"/>
        <MenuItem Header="_Close"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

...

```
private void Menu_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Menu menu = (Menu)sender;
    menu.Background = Brushes.White;
}
```

Comment: @Thanks. Then what about when I move the mouse out of the menu to other parts of the UI, does it mean I should write events to change its background to normal?

Comment: @Vahid No, Triggers take care of that for you

Edit: Nevermind, using events, not triggers. Yes you need to

Comment: @Vahid, are you talking about highlighting just the selected `MenuItem`, or the whole `Menu`?

Comment: @Sheridan Let's say I have File | New, Open, Save and Edit | Cut, Copy, Paste. I want to change the background of File menu item when the mouse is clicked on it. only the main menu not its submenues.

Answer (score 0):

You can rework the Template for the MenuItem (not the Menu). To reproduce what I did:

1. Select a MenuItem in XAML
2. Right click it in the designer.
3. Select 'Edit Template'
4. Select 'Edit a Copy'
5. Edit the 'MenuItem.Highlight.Background' SolidColorBrush to a new color of your choosing. (I chose 'Red')
6. Remove the Key from the style for the MenuItem.

You will end up with the following resources if you start from scratch:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Background" Color="Red"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background" Color="#0A000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border" Color="#21000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Selected.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z</Geometry>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Foreground" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Selected.Background}" ClipToBounds="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="10"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="menuHeaderContainer" Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="menuGestureText" Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="#FF999999"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Separator" Color="#FFD7D7D7"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="UpArrow">M 0,4 L 3.5,0 L 7,4 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="MenuScrollButton" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
        <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Hover"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                    <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter x:Key="MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Geometry x:Key="DownArrow">M 0,0 L 3.5,4 L 7,0 Z</Geometry>
    <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
                            <ScrollContentPresenter CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="0" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                    <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <Path Data="{StaticResource UpArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                        </RepeatButton>
                        <RepeatButton Grid.Column="0" CommandTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}" Focusable="false" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource MenuScrollButton}">
                            <RepeatButton.Visibility>
                                <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="100" Converter="{StaticResource MenuScrollingVisibilityConverter}" FallbackValue="Visibility.Collapsed">
                                    <Binding Path="ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="VerticalOffset" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ExtentHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="ViewportHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </RepeatButton.Visibility>
                            <Path Data="{StaticResource DownArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                        </RepeatButton>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" Padding="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Separator}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True"/>
                    <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Disabled.Border}"/>
            </MultiTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Geometry x:Key="RightArrow">M 0,0 L 4,3.5 L 0,7 Z</Geometry>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="22" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid Margin="-1">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="22" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}" Height="22" Margin="-1,0,0,0" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="22">
                    <Path x:Name="Glyph" Data="{DynamicResource Checkmark}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Height="11" Width="9"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="0.7" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Path x:Name="RightArrow" Grid.Column="5" Data="{StaticResource RightArrow}" Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" HorizontalOffset="-2" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right" VerticalOffset="-3">
                    <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" Padding="2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Glyph" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="RightArrow" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Foreground}"/>
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=TopLevelItemTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,0"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=SubmenuHeaderTemplateKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type MenuItem}}}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This looks daunting, but you are basically telling the MenuItem to use another Template other than the one defined in the theme. Personally, I avoid doing such things, as it breaks the themes across the various Windows versions. By doing this, the Menu will look the same on XP, Vista & 8.

You will likely be able to optimize this quite a bit. But I at least recommend you put it in a separate ResourceDictionary.

Comment: Thanks Troels, did you try this? it didn't work for me.

Comment: I understand what you meant now. I have completely rewritten the answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is still missing the part when I want to click the `File` menu for its background to be changed. Say I want it to be `Yellow` when the `File` menu is clicked. I mean the background of the file not its submenues.